# How can I add an array of objects to another class

Tags: c++, arrays, object

I'm new in C++ programming. I'm trying to create an array of objects of one class in an another class.
When I'm trying to run this I'm getting errors. One of the errors is `unknown override specifier`. Can somebody tell me how can I fix this please?

```
class Teacher
{
    Student t[10];
public:

    void setMark()
    {
        t[2].mark = 80;
    }
};

class Student
{
public:

    int mark;

};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what if you define the class `Student` before `Teacher`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time of parsing the definition of `Teacher`, the symbol `Student` is unknown. The compiler does not know that it names a type. My compiler (gcc) throws an error:

```
main.cpp:3:5: error: ‘Student’ does not name a type
     Student t[10];
     ^
```

I did not see any "unknown override specifier". This could be related to different compiler you are using, or some other problem that you are not showing us.

The solution? Define `Student` first, since it does not depend on `Teacher`.

Comment: Why the downvote? I tested it and it works. If there is another problem, it is not given in the question.

Comment: Note that the question claims a different error. The right course of action is to ask for a [mcve]. You have no idea if there's any connection with the code posted and the one OP's actually trying to fix.

Comment: @juanchopanza if that is the right course of action, why are you not asking for it?

Comment: @CygnusX1 It was the first thing I did (via the appropriate close vote.)

Comment: @juanchopanza without any comment, that could be seen as a little agressive, don't you think? Leaving a comment explicitly asking for a MCVE is also a possible way

Comment: @wasthishelpful: Do you insist, that this question adds **anything** useful to this Q&A site? This is someone, too lazy to read books. This is not the intended Stack Overflow audience.

Comment: If I modify the code and create another array in student of type class, what class should I declare first?

Comment: @wasthishelpful No need for comment, OP can read the close vote reason and follow any relevant links.

Comment: @ChenChen: Check [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2a6307e1f8b50759) and reconsider.

Comment: @juanchopanza You are showing such a rigid approach. I can accept a question that is somewhat incomplete if I can heuristically figure out what the author has in mind. The code OP posted is there for a reason. It is also minimal and contains an error. Claiming that it is completely unrelated due to a different kind of error being mentioned is formally correct, but practically - I would say - too pedantic.

Answer (score 1):

Simply swap the order of your two classes. The compiler has no idea what Student is because it was not declared when the compiler reach to the line `Student t[10];`

By the way, you may want to use `vector<Student>` instead of an array.

Answer (score 1):

You are using student object in the class teacher and it has not even been declared before calling. You have to declare the student class before the teacher if you want to use the former in the latter.

Answer (score 1):

you need to declare student class first or add prototype on top of code

```
class Student
{
public:
    int mark;
};

class Teacher
{
    Student t[10];
public:
    void setMark()
    {
        t[2].mark = 80;
    }
};

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```